# Changing polygons' colors in Maya via Python

Tags: python, maya, texturing

The only way I know is to use a slider:

```
import maya.cmds as cmds

cmds.colorSliderGrp( 'polygonColour', label = "Colour", hsv = ( 1, 1, 1 ) )
```

Then taking the RGB value from that:

```
rgb = cmds.colorSliderGrp( 'polygonColour', query = True, rgbValue = True )
```

And then assigning a material to the polygon and giving that material the color:

```
myShader = cmds.shadingNode( 'lambert', asShader = True, name = "polygonMaterial" )
cmds.setAttr( 'polygon1' + ":blockMaterial.color", rgb[ 0 ], rgb[ 1 ], rgb[ 2 ], type = 'double3' )
```

Is there an easier approach without using a slider and/or without assigning a material?

Comment: Are you trying to set a vertex color that's attached to the geometry? Or to set the color of the shader?

Comment: The colour of the shader.

Answer (score 0):

If you just want to assign a new color to the existing shader(s), it's a simple `setAttr()`.  Every shader has it's own attribute set, so the exact values you need to set depend on the type of shader you want, but for common cases (lambert, phong, and blinn) it's just the `.color` attribute. Setting the color is as simple as passing in the RGB values you want:

```
 cmds.setAttr(shader + '.color', 0, 1, 0)  # green
```

Getting the shader on a particular face is not easy. The easiest thing to do is to get your face and check all the shadingEngine nodes :

```
 for shadingEngine in cmds.ls(type="shadingEngine"):
     if cmds.sets('pCube1.f[0]', im=shadingEngine):
        shaderball = cmds.listConnections(sshadingEngine, type = 'lambert')[0]
        print "face is assigned to %s" % shaderball
```

You can assign a shader to a face by
i
     cmds.sets('pCube1.f[99]', fe='initialShadingGroup')

where the argument to `fe` is the shadingEngine node.  The shader ball - the thing you edit by hand - is connected to the shadingEngine's `.surfaceMaterial` attribute, you can get it the way I did above.

If you want to change the color of a face *without* shader assignment you want to make vertex colors instead.  The menu is **Color > Apply Color**, the command is `polyColorPerVertex (faces, rgb=(r,g,b)`. So setting the color of one face on a cube looks like

```
 cmds.polyColorPerVertex('pCube1', rgb=(1,0,0)) # red
```

The display of the vertex colors in the viewport is controlled by the `.displayColors` attribute or the **Colors > Toggle Display Colors Attribute** menu item.