# Maya color per vertex not working

Tags: python, maya

I am quite new to Maya, and I'd like to make some small tests, in this case, coloring a cube by assigning each vertex a color. Reading the documentation I've come to this small code:

```
import maya.cmds as cmds

cmds.polyCube(sx=2, sy=3, sz=2, h=3, name='testobj')

tot = cmds.polyEvaluate(v=True, f=False) 

print "vertex count =", tot

for i in range(tot):
    cmds.select('testobj.vtx[' + str(i) + ']')
    v = cmds.pointPosition('testobj.pt[%d]' % i)
    print v, type(v)
    cmds.polyColorPerVertex('testobj.vtx[%d]'%i, colorR=1.0, colorG=0.3, colorB=0.8)

#rgb=((1.5+v[0])/3.0, 0.3, 0.8)
#cmds.polyColorPerVertex('pTorusShape1.vtx[%d]'%vertNum,r=r,g=g,b=b);

cmds.refresh()
```

The code won't change any color in the scene. I've followed of course the [original docs](http://download.autodesk.com/us/maya/2011help/CommandsPython/polyColorPerVertex.html), [this SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29088105/changing-polygons-colors-in-maya-via-python), and [this code](http://nullege.com/codes/show/src@n@g@ngSkinTools-HEAD@ngSkinTools@python@ngSkinTools@experimental@userpaint.py/99/maya.cmds.polyColorPerVertex).

I missing something really basic here, I am sure.

Any hints?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your code work exactly like what you want .. You just need to display it :)

add this before refresh

```
cmds.setAttr("testobjShape.displayColors",  1)
```

Comment: May I ask you, I am starting from scratch, so am I better off with pyMEL, or with CMDS?